# tf frames position odomotry

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to get the position of my robot based on odometry, so I have two encoders that are connected to the front wheel. I am trying to follow this REP http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html but I could not understand is that why the odom frame is considered as a father frame in relation with the base link. If there are here people who could clarify that for me because the odometry encoder is considered as a sensor and it should be the children of the base link. To clarify more I have a world frame then a base_link then to odometry encoders.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285967/tf-frames-position-odomotry/) by [haysgh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28793/haysgh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The REP you referenced is a document that is describing best practices and standards used for coordinate systems in mobile robots in ROS. If you choose to follow those conventions, then indeed, the odometry frame (typically `/odom` would be a parent of the base frame (typically `/base_link`). The computer on your robot would need to read the values from the wheel encoders and integrate the kinematics of your robot to provide an estimate of where your robot is relative to where it started. This would be provided to the rest of the ROS world as a transform from the odometry to the base frame (and typically a topic of type [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html)). If your robot never had any drift, wheel slippage, integration error, etc. then the transform from a truly world-fixed frame to the odometry frame would be constant; of course, this will never happen and there will always be drift in your odometry estimate.

Typically the location of the sensors themselves would be described by further transforms that are children of the base frame (e.g. `/base_link` -> `/sensor_1`). This is usually done with a URDF and a [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher).

There are likely other choices that could make sense for describing this same information (you seem to have an idea of how you would prefer this same information to be described), and you are free to use whatever description you want. That being said, beware that if you don't follow the REP, there are many other packages that may not work with your robot.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haysgh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28793/haysgh/) on 2018-03-20**:
Thank you for your answer it really clarified many things. I am willing to use the [robot_localization_package](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) in the future that's why I should follow the REP. For more clarification the real position of the robot is defined by the base frame not the odom ?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-03-20**:
The "real" position is more complicated than that. Definitely, robot_localization is designed to fuse sensors and provide an estimate of the position of the robot by publishing a transform from an "odom" frame to a "base" frame.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-03-21**:
I suggest you study the picture on this [robot_localization wiki page](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html). Note that the `odom` frame is created facing the same direction as the robot. IIRC the `map` frame **should** face True or Magnetic North.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-03-21**:
The heading of `map` depends somewhat on how you've set up `navsat_transform`. Due to ROS conventions and how these localization packages tend to work, the position of the robot in the `odom` frame tends to drift...

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-03-21**:
So the "real" position of your robot is (usually) the pose and orientation of `base_link` relative to `map`